# equivalent definition of proper discontinuous action on metric space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have the following question:

We know that an action of $G$ on $Y$ is proper discontinuous if for each $y\in Y$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $U\cap g(U) \neq \phi$ only when $g$ is the identity.

Take the special case ;

Take  $Y$  to be a metric space and $G-$action to be action by isometry. Is there any equivalent definition for showing that the group action is proper discontinuous

Comment: Incidentally, the definition you are using is not a good one (for instance, $Y/G$ need not be Hausdorff) but it's OK for isometric actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y \in Y$, let

$$\delta(y) = \inf \: \bigl\{ d(y,gy) : g \in G \setminus \{e\}\bigr\}.$$

Then the action is properly discontinuous if and only if $\delta(y) > 0$ for all $y\in Y$.

For if the action is properly discontinuous, then in particular for each $y\in Y$ there is an $\varepsilon(y) > 0$ such that $gy \notin B_{\varepsilon(y)}(y)$ for $g \neq e$, so $\delta(y) \geqslant \varepsilon(y) > 0$.

Conversely, if $\delta(y) > 0$, then $B_{\eta(y)}(y) \cap g\bigl(B_{\eta(y)}(y)\bigr) = \varnothing$ for all $g\in G\setminus \{e\}$ if $\eta(y) \leqslant \delta(y)/2$ since the action is by isometry.